# How to detect browser internal width for mobile devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

I want to detect mobile browser internal height for all mobile devices. If it is not possible then can we fix mobile mode like portrait or landscape any of one permanent as a fix mode for mobile site. I am using this but unable to get exact internal height.

```
$(window).height();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try **[innerWidth()](http://api.jquery.com/innerwidth/)** to get the mobile internal width like

```
var mobileWidth=$(window).innerWidth();
var mode='POTRAIT';
if($(window).width() > $(window).height())
{
    mode='LANDSCAPE';
}
alert(mode);
```

Comment: any other solution, it is useful but not full fill my full requirement, I want mobile browser inner width or can i fix like browser can only display in only portrait or landscape, in one of them.